# What is the syntax to define an Oracle procedure within an another stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

After many Google and SO searches, I cannot find a definitive answer to this simple question:

How can I define a procedure inside of another procedure to use?

I know that there are nested blocks and nested procedures, but I haven't seen the exact syntax for what I want. i.e.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TOP_PROCEDURE
(...)
IS
-- nested procedure here?
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Tony's answer is spot on, but I have to ask why you'd want to do this.  I've seen nested procedures used, but I've never seen them used well.  That is, you'd almost always be better off putting the procedure in a package (if it's not already in a package) and creating private methods in the package for the nested procedures.  Otherwise, it gets rather confusing to follow the code and leads to the rather poor practice of essentially having all TOP_PROCEDURE's local variables be global variables in the context of the nested procedures.

Comment: I use nested procedures fairly often - generally for small functions that are very specific to their parent procedure (i.e. they just don't make any sense to be callable by anything else), where otherwise I'd be repeating the same code more than once in the parent procedure.

Comment: You're point is definitely valid Justin, but in truth I'm just using it in the way Jeffrey specifies. It was also really a question out of curiosity as well. It's a quick way to refactor my code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE TOP_PROCEDURE
(...)
IS
   variable NUMBER;
   PROCEDURE nested_procedure (...)
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL;
   END;
   PROCEDURE another_nested_procedure (...)
   IS
   BEGIN
     NULL;
   END;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

Local procedures must be declared **after** anything else (e.g. variables).

Comment: Simple and fast answer. Awesome.