# Using output from Procedure in another Procedure in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that looks like this:

```
    create or replace procedure proc1 (prc out sys_refcursor, <filter variables>) 
    as 
    begin
    open prc for (select * from blah blah blah.. <logic using filter variables,  
    calculations,etc> 
    end proc1
```

I was wondering if it is possible to use the output from this procedure in another procedure to further filter the data I am looking at and do more calculations. Is there a way to pass the sys_refcursor to another procedure and select into that (probably a bad idea)? Or would a temporary table help here?

I understand that I could make this into one procedure but I need the data from both separately as they are both relevant to what I am doing.

Comment: do you mean like using a SELECT within a SELECT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the syntax to define an Oracle procedure within an another stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929361/what-is-the-syntax-to-define-an-oracle-procedure-within-an-another-stored-proced)

Comment: No in essence what I want to do is make a procedure that will `SELECT * FROM proc1(variables)`. I want the output of a procedure to be passed to another separate procedure.

Comment: you can create two separate procedures and call one of the procedures in the other one when a correct validation has occured

Comment: Calling one procedure from within the other is what I want to do, however will I be able to further manipulate the data that is outputted from the procedure called within the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you wrapped your result set in a cursor, your sql options are limited. You can of course pass the cursor to another function and *fetch* from it there. But you'll have to do all the dirty filtering work yourself.

Still passing cursors around is sometimes a valid design pattern. Typicall you will fetch from the cursor and generate other selects from that. However, in your case you want *to further filter your data*, and in this case a cursor is not a good choice in general, because you loose the power of SQL.

If you really want to do such a thing you can use *pipelined functions*. In contrast to cursors these allow you to create a (virtual) table where you can use plain old select again. And of course you can create such a pipelined function when given a cursor by fetching from it and invoking *pipe row* repeatedly.

But all of this is tedious and requires quite some boilerplate code.

In general there is not much penaltly in just writing multiple selects with different where clauses. If you want to explicitly encode that these selects are restriciting the result set more and more, use select from select, maybe placing the inner selects into a view, thus creating a hierarchy of views.